# How to start Apache Kylin?

Tags: hadoop, kylin

I am trying to install apache kylin 1.5.4.1,I am following this URL:

http://kylin.apache.org/docs15/install/index.html

while starting the server i am getting like this,

```
$kylin.sh start

KYLIN_HOME is set to /usr/local/kylin
cat: /usr/local/kyli: No such file or directory
cat: /conf/kylin.properties: No such file or directory
-mkdir: Not enough arguments: expected 1 but got 0
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -mkdir [-p] <path> ...
failed to create , Please make sure the user has right to access
```

If any body is using Apache Kylin please tell me,prerequisites,how to install and how to start kylin server.please guide me.

Comment: I ran it within the Cloudera Quickstart VM just last week. `bin/kylin.sh start` was the only thing I did

Comment: Your problem seems to be `cat: /usr/local/kyli: No such file or directory`... If you look closely, that probably should read `/usr/local/kylin`

Comment: Thanks for reply,How can i install kylin in my VM,otherwise i have to use anyone like HDP,cloudera mandatory.

Comment: I didn't install anything. Went to that site, downloaded the `tar.gz` file for `CDH 5.7/5.8`, then just ran that command after extracting it

Comment: thank you for reply.but I am not able to understand how to install kylin in my VM.Now i am not using cloudera.

Comment: As I said, it isn't installed. It is downloaded, extracted, and ran. The site from the documentation is correct. The script that you downloaded seems to be corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your hadoop installation path has been setup on your environment variables

```
> export HADOOP_HOME=/home/user/hadoop-2.7.2 
> export HIVE_HOME=/home/user/hive-2.0.0 
> export HBASE_HOME=/home/user/hbase-1.2.4 
> export KYLIN_HOME=/home/user/kylin-1.5.4.1

> export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HIVE_HOME/bin:$HBASE_HOME/bin:$KYLIN_HOME/bin$PATH
```